# git clone HTTP request failed with empty error message

Tags: git

When attempting to clone a repository I get the following error message:

```
> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/deploy/tmp/<PROJECT_REDACTED>/.git/
> error:  while accessing
> https://<PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_REDACTED>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<USER_REDACTED>/<PROJECT_REDACTED>.git/info/refs
> 
> fatal: HTTP request failed
```

How can I find out what the HTTP request failure was?

Notice that there are two spaces after `error:`. A search for this issue on the Web usually shows some sort of error message there like "403 forbidden" before the " while accessing" part of the error message.

I have tried adding `-verbose` and `-vvvv`, but I get no more error output.

Comment: It turned out the issues was related to cert validation in openssl. I had to `yum update openssl` to get this working. I am leaving the question open, because I still never got an answer on how to get a more verbose error message from `git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `git` command with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`